# Replace a select input with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a page with a form where I have 2 selections, and when you select value `X` on the first selection, it will change the second selection.
I tried doing this with:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
function makeRequestObject() {
    var xmlhttp = false;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        } catch (E) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

function replace2(id) {
    var xmlhttp = makeRequestObject();
    var file = 'http://example.com/index.php/result/new_select/'
    xmlhttp.open('GET', file + id, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var content = xmlhttp.responseText;
            if (content) {
                document.getElementById('replace').innerHTML = content;
                //$( "div.test" ).replaceWith(content);
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null)
}
</script>
```

And in the form I have this:

```
<th id="replace">
    <?php
    $fruit_options = array();
    $fruit_options[-1] = 'Select ALL';
    foreach ($tests as $fruit) {
        $fruit_options[$fruit->ID] = $fruit->Nume;
    }
    echo form_dropdown('test', $fruit_options, $fruit->ID, $fruit->Nume);
    ?>
</th>
```

Everything  works, when I select the first dropdown, the second selection will be modified (I call it with: `echo form_dropdown('test1', $fruit_options, -1, 'onchange="replace2(this.value)"');`)

But when I press "Submit", the controller will not see the value of post `test`.

In `result/new_select/id` I have something like this:

```
<?php
$fruit_options = array();
$fruit_options[-1] = 'Select ALL';
foreach ($tests as $fruit) {
    $fruit_options[$fruit->ID] = $fruit->Nume;
}
echo form_dropdown('test', $fruit_options, $fruit->ID, $fruit->Nume);
?>
```

Does anybody know why my code doesn't work, or what a better way to do this would be?

**LE**

```
        <form action="http://example.com/index.php/test/query" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">    
<table>                    
        <th>
            <select name="test1" onchange="replace2(this.value)">
                <option value="-1" selected="selected">Select ALL</option>
                <option value="515">515</option>
                <option value="252">252</option>
                <option value="327">327</option>
                <option value="409">409</option>
            </select>                        
        </th>
        <th id="replace">
            <select name="test" 315>
                <option value="-1">Select ALL</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="315" selected="selected">315</option>
            </select>                        
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Search!"  />                            
        </th>
</table>
    </form>
```

In controller i see value for `test1` but i can't see value of `test`.

Comment: Given that the vast majority of browsers in use support XMLHttpRequest, it would be much better to try that first, then do the MS *try..catch* thing. Please post sample HTML received by the browser, not the server code that generates it.

Comment: you need to provide all your HTML so that we can see where you are placing these `select` , the reason may be because they are not inside the `form` tags.

Comment: why are you placing this inside `<th>` tags? I think you want to do `<tr>` and wheres your closing `</form>` tag?

Comment: I forgot </form> to copy.

Comment: Also why is there a `315` as an attribute of your `select` : `<select name="test" 315>` ? this might break your code.

Comment: Resolved that and still can't see the value in controller.

Comment: Also where are your opening and closing `<table></table>` tags? Fix that, and update your question so we can see what you have.

Comment: Updated, problem it's not there... some how, after i update <th id='replace'> that <select> will not be in <form>.

Comment: And i made a test, if i look with `view source` (`ctrl+u`), i will see the first code, not the new code with new values with i can see on page. But with `inspect element` i see the code of page modified.

Comment: I dont see in your code that you changed the `<th>` to `<tr>` Change that and try it

Comment: You are also missing `<td>` tags for your `table` columns. If you dont structure your table correctly, the elements will be misplaced.

Comment: with _"view source"_ you will not be able to see what Javascript has changed in the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here seems to be your table structure. You are forgetting that tables need rows `<tr>` and columns `<td>`, therefore when JS appends any HTML, it places them outside the `form` thus your form request not sending the right POST info.

Restructure your table like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php
                $fruit_options = array();
                $fruit_options[-1] = 'Select ALL';
                foreach ($tests as $fruit) {
                    $fruit_options[$fruit->ID] = $fruit->Nume;
                }
                echo form_dropdown('test1', $fruit_options, -1, 'onchange="replace2(this.value)"');
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="replace">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```